# How to run custom IntelliJ inspections from terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, scope, inspect

so I'm currently trying to run IntelliJ's code inspector from the command line, but I can find where to put in a custom scope. There is an option for custom directories to scan, but nothing for plugging into their custom scope language. Has anyone else dealt with this before? [IntelliJ's Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-intellij-idea-features-from-command-line.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `idea.analyze.scope=SCOPE_NAME`[[1]](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135512) to your custom properties using the `Help | Edit Custom Properties...` menu item. Replace `SCOPE_NAME` with the name of the scope you want to use. This scope you will have to define inside your IDE. If the scope cannot be found, the entire project is inspected. [[2]](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInspection/InspectionApplication.java#L164)

Comment: Can I run this on the /Contents/MacOs/studio executable? Or does it have to be inspect.sh?

Comment: You can use the studio executable if you want, that's also what inspect.sh does.

Comment: Hey, for some reason, when I added it onto my argument list, the inspection stopped working and listed the available commands. Is there something special I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Or maybe there is a slightly different way for executing in Android Studio? I already tried -Dstudio. and -studio. though. I just tried running with idea instead of studio, and it did the same thing.

Comment: No, the property should be the same for Android Studio. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Where exactly does the property go? I can't find where to put it exactly. (In the arguments list.)

Comment: In the `idea.properties` file in the bin directory of your Android Studio installation. Is it not working?

Comment: No it isn't, I also tried putting it in ~/Library/Preferences/Android Studio 2.1/idea.properties, maybe that needs to be a different one, but I tried it in the /bin, so I don't know if it matters.

Comment: I've also tried putting `-Didea.analyze.scope=xxx` into the `studio.vmimports`.

Comment: I have again modified my answer with the official way to edit properties. Maybe this will help. (it's working for me btw)

Comment: Maybe it's a local computer issue. I wonder what could be inhibiting me though.

Comment: It finally started working after re-editing the vmoptions. I don't know why. It's just working...